# To get top 'n' count of column1 group by column2

Tags: sql, oracle

my table

```
    column1 column2
    1       10/05/2015
    2       10/05/2015
    3       05/11/2017
    4       06/09/2017
    5       07/10/2017
...
...
1000        07/06/2017
```

i want to get top 3 count of column1 group by column2

```
count(column1) column2

20              10/05/2015
10              05/11/2017
8               07/06/2017
```

I can get a query to get the count of column1 based on column2. how to get the top n rows?

```
select count(*), column2 
from table1 
group by column2 
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: where rownum < n+1

Comment: Google: oracle + top n - depending on your oracle version `where rownum < n` or something with rank - calculation will help you

Comment: rownum will not work here i guess. I'm not sure on how to use RANK() here! @PatrickArtner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/top-n-queries

(Maybe:  - not sure, dont have oracle at hand)

```
SELECT c, c2
FROM (
    select 
       count(*) c, 
       column2 c2, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (Order by count(*) DESC) val_rank 
    from table1 
    group by column2
) 
WHERE val_rank <= 5
```

Dense rank should be what you need. It will assign a rank to each result, same rank to same result and the calculated rank is without gaps, so limiting that to your 5 should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

in case of oracle you can use the keyword `rownum` in your where clause

so in your query add

```
where rownum < 4
```

if you want to show first 3 results

Comment: Here i need to top 5 count, not top 5 rows. if i added rownum < 5, it will only consider top 5 rows in table1 to get the count. But, i need to find count for all the date and i need to pick first 5 rows. Thanks